# Should I just go to grad school during the pandemic or go to industry?

Tags: career-path

I've just got an offer from a top graduate program in Computer Science and also got an offer from the big company. I'm very happy and grateful for these opportunities, but I can't decide which one to choose. I managed to get into Master program with thesis option, but I haven't been assigned to any supervisor. I wanted to pursue graduate studies in ML (which was my goal after graduation), and we are usually given one or two semesters to find an academic supervisor. For these reasons, in-person interaction with professors is considered a very important opportunity to "get to know each other", but I'm afraid that this will unlikely to happen during the pandemic.

In the meantime, I have been job-hunting for more than 6 months. Out of hundreds of applications, only < 10 companies returned back to me. It didn't surprise me because I only have 4-month internship and 1-year research during undergraduate studies. Working at the company will definitely open doors to future opportunities but I feel like I'm deviating myself from my goal and I feel I'm already falling behind in life because I already had one gap year during my undergrad and I took one year break after graduation. Should I just go to grad school, or defer my offer of admission to the next year and work for one year?

Comment: Sorry, but only you can answer this. Make a list of pros and cons of each option and choose one. I doubt the pandemic should be the deciding factor.  Good luck.

Comment: Please improve the English of the question. E.g., what does "The top graduate program" mean? "The top company"? I think you meant "**A** top graduate program" instead.

Comment: @Buffy Yea the problem is I'm not sure what to expect from online classes, especially in graduate programs.

Comment: Impossible to reassure you. Some places will be better than others, both universities and employers, but chaos makes it hard to do sensible things other than to stay safe.